# Multiple XPath attributes and C# HTML Agility pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I'm learning C# and webscraping using HTML Agility Pack and XPath.

I want users to select certain criteria and, according to choices, to present the content in console.

The website I'm using has multiple **li** classes and I have to search all of them, look every **title**, **description** and **price**, and if those match users' input, write the **link** that's in that same **li** class.

[image: Source pic to better explain html]

So far I have this, but it obviously doesn't take into account other criteria and I don't know how to read in console **price** and **description** and return **link**:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load("www.mysite.com");

Console.WriteLine("Insert title");
string title = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Insert description");
string description = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Insert price");
int price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var items = 
  from itemsOnPage 
  in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"[text()[contains(., '{title}')]]")
  select new { Description = itemsOnPage.InnerText };

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is it possible to go through all classes, check if it contains **title**, **description** and **price** and if it does contain it, write the href from that class? I wonder how would i write that in c#?

Comment: So your question really is *"How can I make an XPath expression that checks multiple conditions?"*, right?

Comment: Basically yes, but conditions are user inputs, not predefined in program.

Comment: That's not relevant at this point. It might become relevant later, but currently your first question should be: *"How would an XPath expression that checks two conditions look like?"* and your second question should be *"How can I build that with values from variables?"* The details about the HTML Agility pack or even C# etc are not really relevant to these two questions.

Comment: I kinda agree but i didn't want to spam the site with multiple questions. especially small questions such as those

Comment: Actually it's better to "spam" the site with multiple questions. This works in two ways. For one, you are forced to dissect your task into small bits, which gives you a better overview over what needs to be done. And second, the smaller the bits are, the higher the chance is that someone else has already asked this question so you don't have to. For example, the XPath "multiple condition" problem is really basic (in fact reading the documentation should be your first stop for that). But others have probably asked it, too, if you look for it.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that, i'm still new to this whole thing. I'll try to do that in the future.